# jQuery - use .hover instead of .click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code on my page.

http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/r7ZDm/

As you see it's a list of links, and every time a link is clicked, the popup box opens up right underneath the link in question.

Now, what I need to do is basically the same, except I need to use the .hover event and delay the execution by 2 seconds. So instead of clicking, the user should keep the cursor over a link for 2 seconds.

Sounds simple enough but I can't get the positioning to work properly. here's what I tried:

```
$('a.showreranks').hover(function()
    {   
    $(this).data('timeout', window.setTimeout(function()
        {
            position = $(this).position();   
        $('#rerank_details').css('top', position.top + 17);   
        $('#rerank_details').slideToggle(300);    
        }, 2000));
    },
    function()
    {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    });
```

Can someone modify this to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$('a.showreranks').hover(function()
{   
    var self = this;
    $(this).data('timeout', window.setTimeout(function() {
        var position = $(self).offset();   
        $('#rerank_details').css('top', position.top + 17);   
        $('#rerank_details').slideToggle(300);    
    }, 2000));
},
function()
{
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sWYTF/)

Comment: Hm. Works on the jsFiddle but not on my actual page. I simplified things a bit for this example as the actual code is a lot longer (there's a lot of other functionalities there). Could you take a look here and see if you can figure out why it won't work: http://jovansfreelance.com/booklist/list/Syn/GoT (note that the div id on this page is `#gen_details` and the link class is `.itemshow`

Comment: And the JS is in scripts.js. Hovering over book titles is what opens the div, but it opens on top of the page.

Comment: @robert What is the problem?  The position?

Comment: I have updated my answer.Instead of `jquery.position` you need to use `jquery.offset`. Read more about -> http://api.jquery.com/position/

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/sPYdC/2/)*

```
$('ul').on('mousemove','li',function(e){
    
    var m = {x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY};
    $('#rerank_details').css({left: m.x+20, top: m.y-10});
    
}).on('mouseenter','li',function(){
    
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#rerank_details').stop().slideDown(300);
    },2000);
    $(this).data('timeout', t);
    
}).on('mouseleave','li',function(){
    
    $('#rerank_details').stop().slideUp(300);
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    
});
```

The `setTimeout` will act like a *hover intent* that actually delays the execution for 2 seconds
 and counts the time hovered inside a `data` attribute of the hovered element - that gets 'nulled' on mouseleave.
I added also a few lines of code that will make your *tooltip* follow the mousemove.